# CoreData in WidgetExtension Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to use CoreData in widgetExtension. I created Add Group and was connect app and extension.
I try use entity in TodayExtension, but I have error: `Cannot find 'TestEntity' in scope`.

My fetchRequest, where I have error: `@FetchRequest(entity: TestEntity.entity, sortDescriptors: [])`

PS. I have a manual codegen for entity. Restart xCode and clean build folder doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the File Inspector, check the target membership of the data model file and the manual generated Entity class file. Add the WidgetExtension project if necessary.